# How do I assign different IDs to automatically generated buttons? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The source code below shows a section of an IONIC page. This page is about shapes and the information of the shapes. For each shape 2 buttons are shown on the page: shape-properties-button and material-information-button. My question is if I have the possibility to give the buttons different IDs?

For example: I have a page with 2 shapes. Shape1 with two buttons shape-properties-button and material-information-button.
and Shape2 with the same 2 buttons.
I want the buttons material-information-button of Shape1 and Shape2 to behave differently.

```
<ion-row class="datatable-content" *ngFor="let shape of shapeGroup.shapes; index as j">
        <ion-row class="content-row">
          <ion-col size="2">
            {{shape.externalid}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="6">
            {{shape.shapeName}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="4">
            {{shape.shapeType}}
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class="options-header">
          <ion-col size="6" size-xs="6" size-sm="6" size-md="6" size-lg="6" size-xl="6">
            <ion-buttons>
              <ion-button id="shape-properties-button" class="table-button-detailview"
                (click)="selectShapeProperty(j)">
                Details
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="6" size-xs="6" size-sm="6" size-md="6" size-lg="6" size-xl="6">
            <ion-buttons>  
              <ion-button id="material-information-button" class="table-button-detailview" 
                (click)="selectBridgeInformation(j)">
                Brückeninformationen
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>         
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row *ngIf="shouldShapePropertyBeShown(j)" size="12" class="content-subrow" id="shape-properties" >
          <ion-col size="4" *ngFor="let property of shape.shapeProperties" style="margin-top: 8px; background-color:#f9efef; ">
           <div class="detailView__label">{{property.propertyName}}</div> 
           <div class="detailView__text"> {{property.propertyValue}}</div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row *ngIf="shouldBridgeBeShown(j)" size="12" class="content-subrow" id="shape-properties" >
          <ion-col size="12" size-xs="12" size-sm="12" size-md="12" size-lg="12" size-xl="12">
              <ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus pass `shape` in both of those buttons as second param

```
<ion-button id="shape-properties-button" class="table-button-detailview"
       (click)="selectShapeProperty(j,shape)">
           Details
</ion-button>
```

and in the methods check the shape type and do actions accordingly.

```
selectShapeProperty(index,shapeObj){
 switch (shapeObj.shapeType){
   cases 'Circle':
     do something;
   case ....
      ....
   default:
     console.error('unknown shape')
 }

}
```

**Note**: In your provided code, I don't see a point in creating `id` in `ngFor` unless they are unique.

---

## Update:

try

```
 <ion-button [id]="'shape-properties-button-'+(j+1)" class="table-button-detailview"
                (click)="selectShapeProperty(j)">
                Details
              </ion-button>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick reply. The ngFor is in the first line of the source code. But how can a second parameter help me to change the ids of the autogenerated buttons?

Comment: I would prefer that for Shape1 the button has the ID shape-properties-button1 and for Shape2 shape-properties-button2 and so on.

Comment: @Doncarlito87: check the updated answer

Comment: this seems to work. Could I also create a function that creates different boolean variables depending on the number of buttons?

Comment: @Doncarlito87 Please mark this as answer and upvote so that it can be helpful for others looking for something similar

Comment: @Doncarlito87 : I would recommend you to create a function and decorate the object[] `shapeGroup.shapes` with a property as `btnId` using some forloop or `map`.  I would not recommend you to call a method in `html`  to create a dynamic id, because that method will be called in every change detection cycle.